# Non-finite function value with integrate() R although solution exists

Tags: r, function

I would like to calculate the following integral in R:

```
print(integrate(function(x){((1.-x)^2)/(abs(1.-x))^(1/3)},lower = 0, upper = 1.6, abs.tol = 1E-7)$value)
```

And I get this error:

> Error in integrate(function(x) { : non-finite function value

However, when I integrate up to 1.600001 or 1.599999, it works and yields 0.4710365 and 0.4710357.

But there is nothing special with this function at the point 1.6... So it should be some strange numerical problem in R.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line with @Bhas's answer, I would go for the following solution:

```
> f <- function(x){ifelse(x!=1,((1.-x)^2)/(abs(1.-x))^(1/3),0)} # Set f(1)=0 since it is the limit of 'f' at 1.
> integrate(f,lower=0,upper=1.6,abs.tol=1E-7)
0.4710361 with absolute error < 2.2e-08
```

'ifelse' avoids problems related to a vectorized 'x'

Comment: Nice solution. But you can put anything you like for the third argument of `ifelse`. Try e.g. `10.99` instead of `0`.

Comment: @Bhas, that's true, but 0 is the only correct limit at 1 for this function ;-) Additionally, plugging in 10.99 might lead to false results when calling 'integrate'.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your function like this

```
f <- function(x) {
    r <- ((1.-x)^2)/(abs(1.-x))^(1/3)
    cat("x=",x,"\n")
    cat("r=",r,"\n")
    r
}
```

you can get some idea of what's happening.
Try this

```
z <- integrate(f,lower = 0, upper = 1.6, abs.tol = 1E-7,subdivisions=50)
z
```

And you will see that `integrate` passes a value of `1` to function`f`.
And dividing by `0` (from `1-x)`) gives a `NaN`. This seems to be an artifact of `integrate`.

With the limits you specified you are jumping over a point where the function is undefined.
You can avoid that by doing

```
z1 <- integrate(f,lower = 0, upper = 1, abs.tol = 1E-7)
z1

z2 <- integrate(f,lower = 1, upper = 1.6, abs.tol = 1E-7)
z2
z1$value+z2$value
```

which gives a result of

```
[1] 0.4710361
```

I wouldn't know how to get around this other than by what you did or what I tried.

Comment: But when integrating up to 1.600001, I also pass the undefined value of 1. And also other values above 1 work just fine...So why 1.6?

Comment: In short you not passing the value 1 for `x`. It is `integrate` doing that during the process of approximating the integral. Apparently it depends on the upper limit 1.6  in combination with the lower limit of 0 and this is most likely just caused by your specific function. Look at the output of my  function `f`.